# subscribe to google pubsub with snowflake (running on aws) to ingest payload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, snowpipe

My goal is to subscribe to a pubsub event with snowflake in order to read the payload and store it in a snowflake table.

Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

Even tough i'm not sure if possible, i'd try it by following these steps:

- Create an application that subscribes to your pub/sub topic and reads the messages [you can read docs here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest), and see an example here [enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-client-library)
- Post the contents recieved to a snowflake table using the provided API, [you can read documentation here.](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/index.html)